# Почему <a> элемент не кликабельный

Tags: html, css

Почему  элементы не кликабельны?

```css
body {
    background-color: #212121;
    color:white;
}

header {
    background-color: #303030;
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: end;
    align-items: center;
    padding-right: 2%;
}

.headerTitle {
   position:absolute;
   padding-right: 50%;
   font-size: 28px;
   font-weight: 700;

}

a {
    color:white;
}

.headerLinks a {
    margin-right: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.headerLinks a:hover {
    color: #888888;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>MyFirstSite_copy_2_2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>



<body>

    <header>

<h1 class="headerTitle">Influencers</h1>

      <div class="headerLinks">
          <a href="#">Home</a>
          <a href="#">Contact</a>
          <a href="#">About</a>
      </div>

  </header>


</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`headerTitle` с `position:absolute;` перекрывает блок с ссылками